# detect change on canvas

Tags: jquery, html, node.js, canvas, drawing

I am creating a small drawing app using canvas and node.js.
Lets say there are many users connected to my app - user A, user B etc.

When user A draws anything on the canvas I want to let other users know that user A has drawn something by outputting the drawing on the canvas of the other users.

What I have achieved is by attaching a `click` event on the canvas element. And it works, but the problem is that it works only when user has completed the drawing in one click. I want the drawing to be shared to the other users in runtime like pixel by pixel change. Is there any event for canvas like `.canvaschange()` ?

My code for the click event is -

```
$("#imageTemp").click(function(){
      var can = document.getElementById("imageView");
      var img = can.toDataURL("image/png");
      socket.emit('emit_draw', img, function (data){
        console.log('Emit Broadcast draw', data);
      });
});
```

Comment: Broadcasting the whole canvas data on every change will likely make your app very slow.. Have you thought about just passing the event data on each change, and the receivers can process this event data just like they handle their local drawing events. Also, instead of click, you might need to broadcast on every mousedown, mousemove and mouseup..

Answer (score 0):

Any reason why you're not emitting drawing messages whereever you are calling the actual drawing primitives? It's the drawing stuff you want to share, not the clicks? You could even do your own drawing based on the same kind of messages (listen for the same messages locally and only draw based on those messages).

And another thing you probably want to do to avoid excessive network traffic; capture the drawing events into some kind of queue, and only emit (over the network) messages when there's been at least 1 second (or whatever) since the last addition to the queue was received.

Comment: I am not worried about network traffic, because I am creating this app for my friends and we will be playing it on lan. So i don't think that it will be a problem. I am ready to do all the patch work in this app. Because I am still a noob in node.js

Answer (score 0):

I want to just confirm did you use

at client side

```
$("#imageTemp").click(function(){
  var can = document.getElementById("imageView");
  var img = can.toDataURL("image/png");
  socket.emit('emit_draw', img);
```

});

at server side

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('emit_draw',function(img){
         socketioId = socket.id;
         socket.broadcast.emit('drawed',socketioId,img);
    });
```

and at client side save each users's socket id and also include

```
   socket.on('drawed',function(friendId,img){
         // handle your picture
    });
```